# Django oauth2 google not working on server

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm using outh2 to authenticate. I need it for google calendar v3 api. On localhost everything works fine. But when I publish it on the heroku server I get Application Error (based on error code is timeout - after 30s). I have created separeted google project (for google id and secret).

Here is my code

```
import gflags
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS


def add_event(summary, location, dateTime_start, dateTime_end):

    # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate. This
    # sample uses OAuth 2.0, and we set up the OAuth2WebServerFlow with
    # the information it needs to authenticate. Note that it is called
    # the Web Server Flow, but it can also handle the flow for native
    # applications
    # The client_id and client_secret are copied from the API Access tab on
    # the Google APIs Console
    FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id='##########################',
        client_secret='#######################',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        user_agent='###########',
        #access_type='offline'
    )

    # To disable the local server feature, uncomment the following line:
    #FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False

    # If the Credentials don't exist or are invalid, run through the native client
    # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
    # Credentials will get written back to a file.
    storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
        credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

    # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
    # with our good Credentials.
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    # Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
    # the Google APIs Console
    # to get a developerKey for your own application.
    service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
                    developerKey='###########################')

    event = {
        'summary': summary,
        'location': location,
        'start': {
            'dateTime': dateTime_start,  # '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'Europe/Ljubljana'
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': dateTime_end,   # '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'Europe/Ljubljana'
        },
        }

    recurring_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

    return recurring_event['id']
```

When I call add_event(summary, location, dateTime_start, dateTime_end) from my view on localhost everything works fine (authentication flow is succesfull and event is added to my calendar). But on server I receive timeout.

UPDATE:

I should probably do that somehow..any ideas?

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=.....

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this

            --noauth_local_webserver
```

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I have the same issue using web2py. Exactly the same ...

Comment: Please read my answer bellow. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your app tries to open a browser on Heroku server to do the OAuth2 flow. That explains why it fails on server, but not on your machine.

Instead of using `oauth2client.tools.run`, I'd suggest you implement your OAuth2 integration seperately from `add_event`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem like Chao Wei suggested. First i retreive url like so

```
FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='##############3',
    client_secret='###############',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    user_agent='##############',
)
storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
    oauth_callback = '*your_redirect_url*'
    flow.redirect_uri = oauth_callback
    url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

I redirected user to that. And when he comes to the redirected url I add event like that:

```
FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='##############3',
    client_secret='###############',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    user_agent='##############',
)
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
    oauth_callback = '*your_redirect_url*'
    flow.redirect_uri = oauth_callback
    flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=None)
    storage.put(credential)
    credential.set_store(storage)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
                developerKey='#############################')

event = {
    'summary': summary,
    'location': location,
    'start': {
        'dateTime': dateTime_start,  # '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Europe/Ljubljana'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': dateTime_end,   # '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Europe/Ljubljana'
    },
    }

recurring_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

return ['id', recurring_event['id']]
```

Code can be optimized. Some code is repeating..but it's working :)

Comment: Why did you put much of the `gflags` code over again in the bottom example? You did the same when redirecting?